# Combine first and last name into full name c#

Tags: c#

So here is what I have

```
        txtFull.Text = txtFirst.Text + “\n” + txtSecond.Text;
```

not sure why its not working

Comment: Define `"not working"`? Looks fine to me

Comment: Your quotation marks look wrong to me. Also: Do you really want to insert a newline and is your textbox mulitine ?? Then do use the windows form of "\r\n" for a textbox. Other controls are different but here we need the full two characters!

Comment: or put `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary: `Environment.NewLine` is `"\r\n"` (Windows), not `"\n"`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko i know. it was addition to TaW`s comment. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the quotes `"` (Unicode: U+0022) for strings instead of the [comma quotation mark](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201C/index.htm) `“...”` (Unicode: U+201C and U+201D)

Comment: @MathewGray Glad I could help. If this answer fixed your problem then you can mark it as an answer to close this topic.